# call a python script (.py file) in ArcGIS python

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, raster-calculator, python-window, arcgis-10.8

I have defined a function in my python script that I want to use for a raster calculation.

How can I call a Python script (.py file) and run a function stored inside the script in the ArcGIS desktop python window?

The script is stored locally on my machine.

Comment: Import this module and call function.

Comment: @FelixIP I am getting error after I write import command as:                                  
 >>> import solving_functions_V4
Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named solving_functions_V4                                                  
 Is the error associated with the running directory/file?

Comment: Change directory first to where it saved

Comment: Assuming script is "D:\Path\To\script.py" which contains a function "def myfunc(args):".  Tell python where to find it `import sys` then `sys.path.append(r"D:\Path\To")` then `import script` then call the function `result = script.myfunc(myargs)`.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure of what you're trying to do, perhaps os.system https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-os-system-method/ or subprocess.Popen https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12605498/how-to-use-subprocess-popen-python to call a script from within a script. I hope that helps.